# Complexity of SVD

Tags: matrices, algorithms

I am working with $SVD$. Here they noted that, it's complexity is  $O(n^3)$. I know that we need to find three matrices $ U,V,S $. i.e., If A is a matrix of order $m*n$ then $svd $ of A is $A=U_{m*m}S_{m*n}V_{n*n}$. could u please explain how $O(n^3)$. Thank you.

Comment: Normally you need about $2mn^2 + 2n^3$ as you first bring it to a bidiagonal form by householder transformations and then make the decomposition, sorry this is only for $m\gg n$ as you first triagonolize the matrix and then use the householder. Else you need $4mn^2 - 4 \frac{n^3}{3}$